# Error: Unable to Parse query string for function QUERY parameter 2:NO_COLUMN: Col1

Tags: google-sheets-api

Was checking on a formula based on google form responses. The google form is still working fine, no changes were made.

This is the formula: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X305zFQXje6Xe44nqw_Us_K7Rp1j2OsPavr3SSKlHLg/edit#gid=777943816","TDEF!A800:W"),"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col4, Col7, Col13, Col14, Col11, Col9, Col10, Col17, Col21, Col19, Col23")

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtB2Q.png)

It was working fine two days ago. It was supposed to pull information (the columns) from the responses of a google form (TDEF, in this case) and input them into another google form(TRF).

Both google forms are still working fine, they are taking responses. I've tried testing whether the https sheet in the formula is redirecting to the correct sheet - it was still correct.

I've tried looking at the version history to see if there was an accidental editing, but so far the only changes in the sheet were new responses to the google form.

Also, this may be relevant, but when the error showed up, it was supposed to be pulling data from the 1202nd response of the source form (TDEF). I tried deleting data from the TDEF responses google sheet so it wasn't so overloaded, but even deleting more than 800 responses/ rows, it still showed the same error.